# How do I split a text which contains figures and letters in a specific way?

Tags: python, list, split

I tried to find a solution online. But I wasn't successful. I would like to split a text like this:

that's the original:

```
    '16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“
    Vor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter 

    17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“
    Natürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit

    18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr: „Stumme Schreie“
    „Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu'
```

This is, what I need:

```
    ['16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“
    Vor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter',
    '17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“
    Natürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit',
    '18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr: „Stumme Schreie“
    „Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu']
```

This option would please me as well:

```
    ['16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr'], ['„Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“
    Vor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter'],
    ['17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr'] ['Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“
    Natürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit'],
    ['18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr'], ['„Stumme Schreie“
    „Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu']
```

How can I get there?
I tried the split method and different other possibilities, but it didn't work out... regular expressions split might be an option, but I fail because there are two numbers in each line.

Thank you in advance, Viktor

Comment: Are you trying to split by two lines? Quick n' dirty: `raw_text.split('\n\n')`

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string on two new lines:

```
s = open('test', 'r').read()
s.split('\n\n')
Out[38]: 
["'16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“\nVor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter",
 '17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“\nNatürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit',
 "18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr: „Stumme Schreie“\n„Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu'"]
```

Then you can split more on single new lines('\n') or colons(':') if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

First requirement:

```
import pprint
text = """'16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“
Vor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter 

17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“
Natürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit

18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr: „Stumme Schreie“
„Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu'"""

pprint.pprint(text.split('\n\n'))
```

Output:

```
['16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“\n'
 'Vor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter ',
 '17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr: „Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“\n'
 'Natürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit',
 '18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr: „Stumme Schreie“\n'
 '„Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu']
```

Second requirement:

```
lst = text.split('\n\n')
lst2 = [[elem] for elem in sum((i.split(': ',1) for i in lst), [])]
print(lst2)
```

Output:

```
[['16.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr'],
 ['„Mein Schwiegervater, der Camper“\nVor einigen Jahren hat die ARD-Tochter '],
 ['17.11., ARD, 20.15 Uhr'],
 ['„Tatort: Die Pfalz von oben“\nNatürlich knüpft der Jubiläums-„Tatort“ mit'],
 ['18.11., ZDF, 20.15 Uhr'],
 ['„Stumme Schreie“\n„Erschütternd“ ist als Begriff fast noch zu']]
```